# Visual indicator for "moved", "closed" and "migrated" Qs

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Could we please have some sort of colored background for the Q-states I mentioned in the title?

Maybe…

- orange for "moved"
- red for "closed"
- and blue for "migrated"

Currently they look like if they'd still be open (and often not answered because of their state).

Thanks.

Comment: nice idea .....

Comment: As a corrollary: perhaps moved, closed, and migrated questions shouldn't appear in the open/unanswered questions list?

Answer (score 1):

The visibility of these questions is [intended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107153/remove-downweight-closed-questions-in-hot-question-sort):

> I think there's a misconception here -- closing does not mean "get this off my screen ASAP", closing means, "this question should be re-evaluated by the community".

We moderators *rely* on your checks.

If these questions were colored differently you would train yourself to ignore them even more than now. That is not how we should work together.

There is already a view for open questions only: Search for [migrated:0 closed:0](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=migrated:0%20closed:0).

Comment: That may be true for **closed** questions, but not for **moved** or **migrated** (nb: I have no idea what the difference is between these two?) questions. If they've been migrated *away* from WPSE, we can safely ignore them; if they've migrated *to* WPSE, well then, they just may warrant special attention. Either way, @kaiser's suggestion of some visual indicator of status is reasonable.

Comment: @ChipBennett Questions are **moved** between the main site and `meta` or they are **migrated** from one site to another (Stack Overflow to WordPress for example).

Comment: @toscho technically the meta "move" is also a migration and functions identically

Comment: @BenBrocka Yes, but it is still **ours**, so a different term is useful. :)